# how do i connect to oracle with the info i have?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, oracle

i have the info below from the oracle DBA and want to connect to oracle from a .net application. i just got done installing the oracle tools/ drivers for windows/ .net and now want to get a console app to connect tot he oracle DB and extract data from oracle into SQL server.

another solution would be to have SQL server pull from oracle all the records in the bugs table. i have no clue what the oracle connection string is and have tried to create a system DSN but failed at that prior to turning to the SO gurus...

> ORACLE SQL user name is ‘USER_dev’,
>   password is ‘welcome’.
>
> Connection string is
>   ‘jdbc:mercury:oracle://qct-ds2-p.apps.com:1139;sid=QCTRP1’

Comment: I hope that is not the real password....

Comment: all the parts of the data have been modified. but the info was kept in tact.

Answer (score 1):

i got lucky and found a simple solution that is all in .net and requires nothing more than this syntax by way of a connection string. all the .ora stuff is presented in the connection string and works well.

```
static void getData()
        {
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                //Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
                //Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}", connection.ConnectionString);

                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM BUG";
                //string sql = "SELECT table_name FROM user_tables";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //string myField = (string)reader["Project"];
                    string myField = (string)reader[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }

        }

        static private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "User Id=USER_dev;Password=welcome;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
                    "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=111.123.479.24)(PORT=1139))" +
                    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=QCTRP1)));";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

go into your ORACLE_HOME\network\admin directory.  Create a file called tnsnames.ora if it is not there already.  Add this into it:

```
QCTRP1.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = qct-ds2-p.apps.com)(PORT = 1139))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = QCTRP1)
    )
  )
```

I'm making some assumptions here...

does qct-ds2-p.apps.com resolve?
looks like the DBA set it up the listener on port 1139... default is normally 1521 so you'll need to confirm.

You can then set up a connection string as follows:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@QCTRP1.WORLD", "dev", "welcome");
```

Comment: @kacalapy oracle_home is the directory where Oracle is installed

Comment: found it, added the txt to the file. can not get the .net code to run a "select * from BUG" and stuff teh data into a dataset. please help.

Answer (score 0):

now that you have the tnsnames created from @erbsock, you will need to get the .net side of 
things working.  Oracle has several tutorials available to help you in this matter.

When you install the [Oracle ODP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (in the link you will see samples as well as the downloads) drivers you will get a directory created in the 
%oracle_home%\odp.net\samples\4\DataSet\DSPopulate\src
(this appears to be the same example as located @ http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/windows/odpnet/DSPopulate/ViewProducts.cs.html)

as an initial test I would recommend just changing around the id/passwrd/sql/etc and trying it out.

it is not that fundamentally different than using System.Data; but there are a few gotchas and remember that each computer will need to have ODP/Oracle client installed to have them work with the ora connection.

if you have any problems post the exact error msg that is displayed as well as a snippet of your .net code that establishes the connection, does the query, and where it is breaking